# Static Variable in C-Style Function within DLL

Tags: c++, c, dll, static

Say there exists a function within a DLL like so:

```
const Object *Get( void )
{
  static Object instance;
  return &instance;
}
```

Where in memory will this static object be located? If this function is called from multiple other DLLs, will more than one copy of this static object exist?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you take explicit action I suspect that it will either end up in the `.bss` section or `.data` section of your executable. When mapped, these are mapped with copy-on-write semantics.

If you want it to be shared you'll need to tell the compiler to place it in a section with the `shared` attribute. The Visual C++ code to do so would look something like the following.

```
#pragma section("mysec",read,write,shared)
__declspec(allocate("mysec")) Object instance = 0;

const Object *Get( void )
{
  return &instance;
}
```

I don't know if you can use `__declspec` when declaring a static variable inside a function.

More documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50bewfwa.aspx)

Comment: You should point out that `__declspec` is Microsoft Visual C++ extension.

Comment: I'm not sure how this relates to my original question? I do want the static variable to exist in one location in memory, and share it across dlls, but I'm not understanding how this helps?

Comment: @RandyGaul Have a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) for a description of copy-on-write. It also helps if you have an understanding of [Virtual Memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Memory) because what I think you want to share is the physical page, not the virtual memory address.